# JavaScript function to categorize data by their "styles" attribute, and store the key-"unicode" pair

Tags: javascript, cyclomatic-complexity

I have a JavaScript function to categorize data by their "styles" attribute, and store the key-"unicode" pair.

Here's my current code:

```
function processMetadata(metadata) {
    let regular = {}, solid = {}, brands = {}
    for (let icon in metadata) {
        let styles = metadata[icon].styles
        let codePoint = metadata[icon].unicode
        if (styles.includes('regular')) {
            regular[icon] = codePoint
        }
        if (styles.includes('solid')) {
            solid[icon] = codePoint
        }
        if (styles.includes('brands')) {
            brands[icon] = codePoint
        }
    }
    return {regular, solid, brands}
}
```

However, CodeClimate keeps complaining about

> Function `processMetadata` has a Cognitive Complexity of 7 (exceeds 5 allowed). Consider refactoring.

I want to resolve this issue, but I'm not aware of any way to further reduce the complexity without reducing the performance of this code. The following snippet does reduce the cognitive complexity to under 5 but at the expense of performance (3+3 loops instead of 1) and extra dependency:

```
function processMetadata(metadata) {
    let regular = _.pickBy(metadata, icon => icon.styles.includes('regular'))
    regular = _.mapValues(regular, icon => icon.unicode)
    let solid = _.pickBy(metadata, icon => icon.styles.includes('solid'))
    solid = _.mapValues(solid, icon => icon.unicode)
    let brands = _.pickBy(metadata, icon => icon.styles.includes('brands'))
    brands = _.mapValues(brands, icon => icon.unicode)
    return {regular, solid, brands}
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve this without having a significant impact on the performance?

Comment: Enforcing a complexity of 5 or lower seems too harsh. Is this a default setting, a personal setting or a team/company setting?

Comment: @konjin It's the default setting. It's not that I have to satisfy the requirement, but I'd just like to know if there is any way to achieve it.

Comment: Could you include an example input and output object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, some code review items;

- Don't skip on semicolons
- You are not changing a number of variables, consider `const` over `let` in those cases
- The names of your styles match the names of your variables, you could use this

Given that, I would consider something like this

```
function processMetadata(metadata) {
    let out = {regular: {}, solid: {}, brands: {}};
    for (const icon in metadata) {
        const styles = metadata[icon].styles;
        const codePoint = metadata[icon].unicode;
        for(const style in out){
            if (styles.includes(style)) {
                out[style][icon] = codePoint;
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: If you make the inner loop an `Array.forEach` then the callback functions content is not counted in the main functions complexity and should reduce the whole thing to 2 (depending on how you count it)

Comment: It would have been `Object.keys(out).forEach()` because `out` is an `Object`. I had considered it and didn't go for it in the end.

Comment: I think the semicolon or the lack of one is more of a personal/organizational preference than an issue? If you look at all the style guides over the Internet, some actually enforce no-semicolon. By the way, the project uses ESLint and it will warn you of any potential pitfall when relying on ASI.

Comment: Thank you, this does reduce the cognitive complexity to 6 (still 1 away from 5 ‍♂️) at the expense of 14% performance(which is acceptable for me).

Comment: Blindman67's suggestion works to get to 5. As for semicolons, I think it is idiomatic and will become more idiomatic over time. No-semicolons smell like a fad to me. (Very personal opinion of course)